# How to parse file with space in its name with Awk

Tags: awk

I have created a script which splits filenames into components for database inserts:

```
find . -name "R*VER"  | while read fname
do
    awk -v squote="'" -v base=${fname##*/} '
        {
            split( base, a, "~" );          
            printf( "INSERT INTO REPORT (COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8)\n" );
            str = sprintf( "VALUES (\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")", base, a[1], a[2], a[3], a[7], a[8], a[9], a[10] );
            gsub( "\"", squote, str );          # replace double quotes with singles
            print str;
        }'
done
```

It worked great until today. New file names have introduced where `a[1]` contains a space e.g `something here~...` .

Now, I have a mix of files that look like this:

`R1~blah~blahblah...VER` and 
`R 4~blah~blahblah...VER`

I want to modify `find` from `find . -name "R*VER"` to `find . -name "* *"` but this will exclude all the files without spaces in the filename.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: put the awk-script in a separate file and use `find . -name ... -exec database_insert.sh {}\;`

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem. Do you want to exclude names with spaces? Do you want to remove the spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [Internal Field Separtor variable, $IFS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF), to a newline, rather than a space.  Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
filenames=`ls`
IFS=$'\n'
for fname in $filenames ; do
    echo "$fname: "
    awk '{print $0}' $fname
done
```

Answer (score 0):

What about enclosing the variable on the command line, like:

`awk ... base="$fname"`

Don't know what that additional `##*/` in your code does, though. Maybe some bash extension...
If you are sure it is OK, enclose it all in double quotes too:

`base="${fname##*/}"`

Comment: Well, I used `base=${fname##*/} ` to remove path+directory name.

Comment: Re ${param##text}: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion - it's a very useful, if arcane, tool in GNU bash.

Comment: @Chris, ok, so try `base="${fname##*/}"`